# Is it safe to create a thread using pthread_create when std::lock_guard is still in scope?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I have a function like following in which threads acquire a lock by using `std::lock_guard` mutex and write to the file via `ofstream`.

When the current file size increases the max size, then I want to create an independent thread that should compress the file and should terminate.

I want to understand the implications of calling `pthread_create` when `std::lock_guard` is still in scope.

Is it safe? Will the lock be applied to the new thread (I don't intend it to be so) as well?

```
void log (std::string message)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtx);

    _outputFile << message << std::endl;
    _outputFile.flush();
    _sequence_number++;
    _curr_file_size = _outputFile.tellp();

    if (_curr_file_size >= max_size) {
        char *lf = strdup(_logfile.c_str());
        // Create an independent thread to compress the file since
        // it takes some time to compress huge files.
        if (!_compress_thread) {
            pthread_create(&_compress_thread, NULL, compress_log, (void *)lf);
        }
    }
}

void * compress_log (void *arg) 
{
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());

    // Code to compress the file
    // ...

   { // Create a scope for lock_gaurd

       std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
       _compress_thread = NULL;
   }
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `pthread_create` with `std::mutex` and not `std::thread`? Btw you have race condition over `_compress_thread`

Comment: "Will the lock be applied to the new thread" only if you have UB in your code. Otherwise it is guaranteed that mutex can be locked only by one thread at a time.

Comment: @Slava, excuse my ignorance, but what is "UB"? 

So the new thread will not be having this lock.

Comment: UB is https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: @Slava, To address the race condition over `_compress_thread`, I have updated the code above. Could you pls check and let know if that's fine?

Comment: Looks better, despite ugliness related to use of `pthread_create`. For example it is possible that `_logfile` could be modified/destroyed making `lf` dangling. `std::thread` would not have this issue. `strdup()` makes it even uglier.

Comment: I will take care of that. Thanks for pointing out the issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mutex works at thread level, it only affects the thread that uses it. When a thread locks a mutex, two things can happen:

1. A mutex is unlocked - it becomes locked and the thread execution continues.
2. A mutex is already locked - the thread does not continue, but waits until the mutex becomes unlocked.

Your new thread runs the `compress_log()` function, which does not access the mutex at all. Consequently, it will run regardless of whether the mutex is locked or not (the mutex in your case will unlock when `log()` exits).

---

An unrelated advise: use `std::thread` instead of `pthread_create`, this way your application becomes more portable:

```
    std::thread{ [lf] { compress_log(lf); } }.detach();
```